# C# allow public incrementation of property, but not explicit seting

Tags: c#, private-members, post-increment

What I want to do is allow the public incrementation of an integer value within my class, *but not allow it to be publicly set explicitly*.

I know that I can create a function like this:

```
void IncrementMyProperty()
```

but I'd like to allow the user to just do this:

```
MyClass.Property++;
```

without allowing this:

```
MyClass.Property = <SomeInt>;
```

It's merely for convenience. I'm just wondering if there is any way to do it.

---

Here's an example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private int _count;

    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
        private set { _count = value; }
    }

    public void AddOne()
    {
        _count++;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass example;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            example.Count++;
    }
}
```

Obviously this won't compile. It's just to show what I'd like to do.

Comment: This isnt possible without doing some goofy stuff like the mentioned operator overloading. It may be for convenience but you end up producing code that is hard to maintain.

Comment: That's what I figured. Thanks though!

Comment: Whose convenience? The method way is a clear and predictable solution. Allowing ++ but not = is not so much convenient but confusing, or are you all alone?

Comment: @TaW I don't see it being confusing. In theory, if someone else tried to use my class wrong my using `=` they would receive an exception that explains why it can't be used that way. It was just a quandary anyhow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's *possible*, but the solution is pretty ugly.

You can create a type that overloads the `++` operator, and make a property of that type where the setter does nothing. That will allow you to use the `++` operator on the property, but it's not possible to actually set the property using the property setter:

```
class MyValue {

  public int Value { get; private set; }

  public MyValue(int value) {
    Value = value;
  }

  public static MyValue operator ++(MyValue v) {
    v.Value++;
    return v;
  }

}

class MyClass {

  private MyValue _count = new MyValue(0);

  public MyValue Count {
    get { return _count; }
    set { }
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Count++;
Console.WriteLine(c.Count.Value); // outputs 1
```

So... using the `++` operator in that way is not a good solution. Normally you don't have a setter that does nothing, that will only be confusing. Having a method that increases the counter is not as short as writing `++`, but it won't be confusing as long as you name it so that it's clear what it does.

Comment: This answer includes a detailed explanation of not only _how_ to do this, but why you _should not_. It provides a means to accomplish what I originally asked. Thus I feel it must be named the accepted answer. The other answers are very informative and should be viewed as well by any future reader.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way. `MyClass.MyProperty++` literally translates to `MyClass.MyProperty = MyClass.MyProperty + 1`, which uses a "setter" and if you allow a "setter" accessor then you would allow, for example, `MyClass.MyProperty = <any value>;`

Comment: It actually calls the `++` operator (that is, it is *not* a literal direct translation). However I believe the re-assignment is inescapable.

Comment: @Keyvan Sadralodabai I figured as much. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: I tried playing around with making Count be a class with overloaded operator ++.  Did not work. The gotcha is that operator ++ is a static function that returns a new instance.  The set accessor is being called.  I'll post the code if anyone wants to see.

Answer (score 1):

not if you increment the int property. but you could write `example++` and overload the ++ operator for your class to increment `Count`, while removing its setter.

Comment: Yes, this is the right method. But it's not exactly what I was trying to do. The actual implementation is inside a much more complex class. Thanks for your help!